# Annotating column tag in azure data catalog

Tags: azure-data-catalog

I am able to annotate description of a table by using asset URL (Location of the table in ADC).

Http request I am using is:

```
{table_location_url}/descriptions?api-version=2016-03-30
```

Json object is:

```
    private static string DescriptionJson(string description)
    {
        return string.Format(@"
        {{
            ""properties"" : {{
                ""key"": ""{0}"",
                ""fromSourceSystem"": false,
                ""description"": ""{1}""
            }}
        }}
        ", Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"), description);
    }
```

Annotating description for table is successful.

Now I am trying to annotate tag for a column using,

```
    Http request:  {table_location_url}/columnTags?api-version=2016-03-30

    static string SampleAnnotationJson(string name)
    {
        return string.Format(@"
        {{
            ""properties"" : {{                    
                ""key"": ""{0}"",
                ""fromSourceSystem"": false,
                ""columnName"": ""on_hold_text_key"",
                ""termId"": ""https://1194df16-3ae0-49aa-b48b-5c4da6e13689-imss-data-catalog.api.datacatalog.azure.com/catalogs/IMSS-Data-Catalog/glossaries/IMSS-Data-Catalog/terms/4b8fe89d-c92a-4aee-abe1-691a2cd52458"",
             }}             
        ", Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));
    }
```

I am getting bad request erro r(400).

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the json request, flower brackets are not closed properly. It works fine with the correction.